# $\lim_{n\to\infty}c^Ta_n$ for $c\in\mathbb R^d$ and $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in \mathbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the two sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in \mathbb R^d$ and $b_n:=c^Ta_n$ for $c\in\mathbb R^d$ so that $a_n$ is bounded and $b_n$ monotone decreasing. From Bolzano-Weierstraß I know that there exists at least one accumulation point $a$ of $a_n$. Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=c^Ta$? I know that the limit exists because $b_n$ is bounded and monotone, but is the limit $c^Ta$?

Comment: Yes it is, because if $(a_{n_k})_k$ is a subsequence converging to $a,$ then $(b_{n_k})_k$ converges both to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$ (as a subsequence) and to $c^Ta$ (by continuity of $x\mapsto c^Tx$).

Comment: @AnneBauval is it possible that $a_n$ has $\geq 2$ accumulation points? If yes, I get $\lim b_n=c^Ta$ and $\lim b_n=c^T\tilde{a}$ for two accumulation points $a\neq \tilde{a}$ so the limit of $b_n$is not unique?

Comment: Yes it is possible and we get $c^Ta=\lim b_n=c^T\bar a$ with $a\ne\bar a.$ That does not contradict the (necessary) uniqueness of $\lim b_n.$

Comment: Here is an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take the sequence $a_n=(1,0)$ if $n$ is even, and $a_n=(0,1)$ if $n$ is odd. Then clearly $a_n$ has two different accumulation points. But the linear function $(x,y)\to x+y$ is constant when applied to $a_n$, hence trivially convergent to $1$. It is easy to come up with a strictly decreasing/increasing example.

Comment: Say $a_n=(1+1/n,0)$ if $n$ is even, $a_n=(0,1+1/n)$ if $n$ is odd and the same linear function.